# Can you interleave calls to SSL_Read() & SSL_Write() when one of them returns SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE?

Tags: ssl, openssl, nonblocking

I have a client program which talks to a server using a message-based protocol. Every request is matched by 1 or more responses.

It's possible for multiple requests to be queued on a socket at once, and the I/O is done on a separate thread using non-blocking I/O. The algorithm is basically to wait for the socket to become readable and/or writable using select() (based on whether there's requests to send and/or responses to read), then to do the read and/or write. This works fine.

Now, if I enable SSL on the socket, we have to use SSL_Read()/SSL_Write() instead of send()/recv(). Now, my question is, can I call SSL_Write() after SSL_Read() fails with WANT_READ/WANT_WRITE (or vice versa), or do I have to keep calling SSL_Write() until it succeeds/fails? The documentation doesn't seem to explicitly rule this out, but it's kind of vague here.

Comment: After some more googling, it seems like it's allowed to mix SSL_read() & SSL_write(): http://marc.info/?l=openssl-dev&m=124312461512355&w=2

Answer (score -2):

> can I call SSL_Write() after SSL_Read() fails with WANT_READ/WANT_WRITE (or vice versa)

If it fails with WANT_WRITE you *must* call `SSL_write().` No 'can I' about it. A read shouldn't fail with WANT_READ, because you *were* reading, except I guess in non-blocking mode.

> or do I have to keep calling SSL_Write() until it succeeds/fails

Yes, when it wants a write you have to write, and you have to repeat until success. No 'or' about it.

I don't really understand why you're even asking. Are there typos in the question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure SSL_read() can fail with WANT_READ if you're using a non-blocking BIO. In any case, the reason I ask is that I would like to be able to do with SSL what I'm now doing without: Reading responses and writing requests 'concurrently', rather than doing a 'write full request, read all responses, repeat' loop.

Comment: Well you have to do whatever it wants. If it wants a read, you have to read. If it wants a write, you have to write. You have to consider that a rehandshake can occur at any time.

Comment: WANT_WRITE does not mean you you have to call SSL_write. It means it's output bio is full and it wants you to empty it so it can write again. The question is can you interleave called to SSL_read and SSL_write when used in this non blocking fashion.